# Clarifying proof for existence of Factor Rings in Gallian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Thrm: Let $R$ be a ring and let $A$ be a subring of $R$. The set of cosets $\{ r+A | r \in R \}$ is a ring under operations $(s+A) + (t+A) = s+t+A$ and $(s+A)(t+A) = st+A$ iff $A$ is an ideal of $R$
>
> Proof: We know that the set of cosets forms a group under addition. Once we know that multiplication is indeed a binary operation on the cosets, it is trivial to check that the multiplication is associative and that multiplication is distributive over addition. Hence, the proof boils down to showing that multiplication is well-defined iff A is an ideal of R. To do this, let us suppose that A is anideal and let $s+A=s'+A$ and $t+A=t'+A$. Then we must show that $st+A=s't'+A$. Well, by definition,**$s= s'+a$ and $t=t'+b$, where $a$ and $b$ belongs to $A$** (1). Then
>
> $$st= (s'+a)(t'+b) = s't' +at'+s'b+ab$$
>
> and so
>
> $$st+A=s't'+at'+s'b+ab+A=s't'+A$$
>
> since $A$ absorbs $at'+s'b+ab$ (2).Thus the multiplication is well defined when A is an ideal
>
> Gallian, 9th ed, page-251

I got that $s$ and $s'$ are in the ring, but why must difference of elements in the ring necessarily be in the subring?

Comment: Well, if $s+A=s'+A$ (as sets) then $s=s+0\in s+A=s'+A$, since $0\in A$, so $s\in s'+A$, meaning that $s=s'+a$ for some $a\in A$.

Comment: Ah yes thanks that helps @Berci